# Pandas - adding a column based on multiple conditions

Tags: pandas

trying to add a boolean column to a df based on two mutually exclusive conditions:

1. `df['Type'] == 'CMBX'`
2. `df['SubType'].isin(['EM','NAHY'])`

they work separately

```
df['Px Quoted'] = np.where(df['Type'] =='CMBX', True, False)
df[df['Type']=='CMBX'].head(5)
Out[72]: 
  Batch  Type SubType  Px Quoted
0   NaN  CMBX               True
1   NaN  CMBX               True
2   NaN  CMBX               True
3   NaN  CMBX               True
4   NaN  CMBX               True
```

or

```
df['Px Quoted'] = np.where(df['SubType'].isin(['EM','NAHY']), True, False)

df[df['SubType']=='EM'].head(5)
Out[74]: 
     Batch Type SubType  Px Quoted
21  NY1530  CDX      EM       True
29  NY1530  CDX      EM       True
36  NY1530  CDX      EM       True
43  NY1530  CDX      EM       True
50  NY1530  CDX      EM       True
```

but the following does not

```
df['Px Quoted'] = np.where(df['Type'] =='CMBX' or df['SubType'].isin(['EM','NAHY']), True, False)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

not sure why it is ambiguous as Type CMBX cannot contain any of Subtype `['EM','NAHY']` Any ideas? is that because its Subtype is blank?

Comment: Use `|` with each condition wrapped in paranetheses, e.g. `(df[col] == 'a') | (df[col2] == 'b')`.

Answer (score 1):

With `np.where` you need to use bitwise operators:

```
df['Px Quoted'] = np.where((df['Type'] =='CMBX') | (df['SubType'].isin(['EM','NAHY'])), True, False)
```

Here I have changed the `or` for a `|`

Comment: need conditions in parenthesis as @jpp suggested, error otherwise

Comment: Added the parenthesis, thanks